# Javascript class access and single entry point?

Tags: javascript, oop

Hi I am new to Javascript coming from C# background. I am having a little issue on how to access one Class from another

I have one entry point javascript file (Main.js included in the script tag in html) and two javascript classes(not included via script tag)

- GameWorld
- Player

I want to use object of GameWord in Main.js, like

```
function init();
{
    this.gameWorld = new GameWorld();
}

init();
```

Similarly I want to use object of Player class in GameWorld class, like

```
class GameWorld
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.player = new Player();
    }
}
```

The GameWorld class uses a library "pixi.js". Is there an easy way to create object and also include the library?
Also, I want to have just one entry point in my HTML script which is the Main.js file instead of adding them in script tag in HTML index page

Thank you and hoping to get a positive reply. Cya!

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript module system

GameWorld.js

It will import the Player.js

```
import Player from "./Player"
//this is relative path.It may change according to your project structure
export default class GameWorld {
  static testGameMethod = function () {
    console.log("I am from game class will call player");
    Player.testPlayerMethod()
  }
}
```

Player.js

```
export default class Players {
  static testPlayerMethod = function () {
    console.log("I am from player class")
  }
}
```

Then in main.js import the GameWorld.js

```
import GameWorld from "./GameWorld";
GameWorld.testGameMethod()
```

Here is a working [**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-z9vr6s?file=index.js).Please check the console to see the output